# Import ecore package / referenced resources in Xtext/MWE2

Tags: eclipse, dsl, xtext

I'm not quite sure how to reference a model I want to use in my Xtext grammar by import in the *GeneratyMydsl.mwe2* file in the *workflow* section.

I the example they reference the model by adding *referencedResource =
        "platform:/resource/org.example.domainmodel/model/Domainmodel.genmodel"*

What does *platform* mean and how exactly do I reference my own model? The file location of my grammar has no real correlation to the file location of the model.

Answer (score 0):

`platform:/resource/project/folder/file` is a uri within eclipse. So `platform:/resource/org.example.domainmodel/model/Domainmodel.genmodel` points to the `org.example.domainmodel` project, `model` folder, `Domainmodel.genmodel` file.

EMF and MWE have facilities to "mimic" that behavour in standalone mode by looking at the folder structure and classpath.

Comment: beyond that: could you be more specific in your question